# Circle radius in r.neighbors in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, r.neighbor

I'm trying to calculate relative relief from a raster in QGIS and I have troubles with square kilometer's cirle radius in r.neighbor.

In ArcMap it's done with **Focal statistics - circular - map units (564) - range** which is almost the same as r.neighbor.

Difference is **I can't find a way to make 1 square kilometer radius** in r-neighbor.

How do I make this happen?

---

So, problem with square kilometer is solved. Did anybody work with r.neighbor and knows how to apply equation for square kilometer in `r.neighbor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area of your circle (1km2) is $\PI R^2$ so you need a radius of $\sqrt(1/\PI)$ to make a circle with a 1 km2 area.

Comment: Thank you for the equation! But now I'm confused, in which part of r.neighbor should i use this equation because the goal is to find maximum and minimum elevation for every square kilometer in raster. I've tried what seems to be best options, after that I tried every option but no luck.

Comment: I have no idea how r.neighbor works - you asked how to set the radius of a circle with an area of 1km2. This sounds like you have an [X Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Then I'm sorry, I guees I have to work on my way of asking questions properly. Nevertheless, thank you for this!